# Problem when attempting to re-direct the output a R Markdown file to a specific location

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a Rmd file that sources to an R script which performs the inital data retrieval and cleaning operations.

My YAML looks like this...

```
title: ''
author: ''
date: ''
output: 
  word_document:
    reference_docx: "docs/template.docx"
```

Within the Rmd I supply an ID that is used to help with the cleaning process in the script.

```
id <- 'MY-ID-01'

library(packages needed)

opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, 
               message = FALSE, 
               warning = FALSE, 
               dpi = 300)

source('scripts/data_cleaning.R') # The id object is needed to run this code
```

This all works fine when I run the files using a standard YAML header but when I attempt to redirect the Word output to the 'docs' sub-folder using this modification to the YAML...

```
title: ''
author: ''
date: ''
output: 
  word_document:
    reference_docx: "docs/template.docx"
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {
      out_dir <- "docs";
      rmarkdown::render(inputFile,
                        encoding=encoding,
                        output_dir=file.path(dirname(inputFile), out_dir))})
```

I get the following error message...

```
Error in eval(parse(test = test, keep.source = FALSE, envir) :
  object 'id' not found
Calls: <Anonymous ... <Anonymous> -> %||% .transformer -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

If I supply the 'id' object directly to the `data_cleaning.R` script, the file is generated and re-directed to the 'docs' sub-folder. Equally, if I transfer all the code from the script into a chunk within the Rmd, it will run without issue also.

Any suggestions as to what is happening here?